# Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4.7 specific user per vhost

Tags: vps, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I've been running Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache 2.2 for some time now using apache2-mpm-itk to be able to specify a user per virtual host.

I've upgraded my VPS to Ubuntu 14.04 which comes with Apache 2.4.7. I've just tried to install apache2-mpm-itk but I'm getting some dependency errors.

```
# apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mpm-itk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-itk libapache2-mpm-itk
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 94.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libapache2-mpm-itk
 amd64 2.4.6-01-1 [9,718 B]
Get:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe apache2-mpm-itk am
d64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4 [1,458 B]
Fetched 11.2 kB in 0s (298 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mpm-itk.
(Reading database ... 59657 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mpm-itk_2.4.6-01-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mpm-itk (2.4.6-01-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-mpm-itk.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-mpm-itk_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-mpm-itk (2.4.7-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libapache2-mpm-itk (2.4.6-01-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mpm-itk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-itk:
 apache2-mpm-itk depends on libapache2-mpm-itk; however:
  Package libapache2-mpm-itk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apache2-mpm-itk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mpm-itk
 apache2-mpm-itk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu so I'm not sure what **No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure** means as I've not installed anything else.

Could please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just create different users and use their home dir as their web root?

Comment: @Vasili Syrakis would that allow for example WordPress to write to the files in that directory? That was the main reason I used the specific users so the apache service was running as the same user that owned the site directory.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be some issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache + mpm-itk. Try with

```
a2dismod mpm_event
apt-get -f install
```

And see how your previously interrupted install continues cleanly.